# AMP form submission into database

Tags: php, forms, amp-html

Form Submission using Amp template is not working, I can't post data from amp-form by using php .Simply No action is getting performed. How to fix it? 
Mypage:  http://samiakhalil.com/theinfotime/amp/register1.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $name;
}
?>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script> 
<form method="post"
action-xhr="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/submit-form-input-text-xhr"
target="_top">
    <input type="text" class="data-input" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" class="data-input" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="button button-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful here.

Comment: visit my page please: http://samiakhalil.com/theinfotime/amp/register1.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMP form submitting with post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346187/amp-form-submitting-with-post)

Comment: I can see that the request is made, but you are pointing to https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/submit-form-input-text-xhr which is returning a json like {"name":"name", "email":"email@email.com"}. You should point to your own server and return a json as well.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<input type="hidden" name="register" value="a">
```

button name is empty, i dont know